# Rotate one UIViewController in UITabBar application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

I have uitabbar application and I Want to rotate just one ViewController with chart in landscape mode. It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to have only one view in landscape mode, while the others are in landscape, nor an easy way to programmatically switch to landscape mode.

One possible approach would be using a `CGAffineTransform` to transform your view in your `viewWillAppear` (i.e., right before the view is shown):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
   //-- Adjust the status bar
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   //-- Rotate the view
   CGAffineTransform toLandscape = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
   toLandscape = CGAffineTransformTranslate(toLandscape, +90.0, +90.0 );
   [self.view setTransform:toLandscape];
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Only if it's modal, if it's part of the tabBarController, you need to support orientation change for all your controller