# UITabBar autorotate issue

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

I'm wondering why iPad project based on `UITabBarController` won't autorotate when i specify some of the tab should autorotate in landscape mode and the other will autorotate in landscape and portrait mode.

i've used the

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

for all the `UIViewController` and specify if landscape `return YES;` other wise `return NO;`

In the other hand, if the `UIViewController should rotate in landscape and portrait i've just`return YES;` always.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for all the `UIViewController` you are loading in tabbarcontroller you must return `True` in

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

Note: 
A tab bar controller will not auto rotate unless ALL the controllers it contains also auto rotate.

from [Rotate one UIViewController in UITabBar application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100309/rotate-one-uiviewcontroller-in-uitabbar-application) -->>

There is no easy way to have only one view in landscape mode, while the others are in landscape, nor an easy way to programmatically switch to landscape mode.

One possible approach would be using a CGAffineTransform to transform your view in your viewWillAppear (i.e., right before the view is shown):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
   //-- Adjust the status bar
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   //-- Rotate the view
   CGAffineTransform toLandscape = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
   toLandscape = CGAffineTransformTranslate(toLandscape, +90.0, +90.0 );
   [self.view setTransform:toLandscape];
}
```

Comment: but i wanna some UIViewController just in landscape, i don't wont it to rotate to the portrait.

Comment: it gives me an error "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:"

Comment: not sure why its giving this error.. but I think you should post a different question on SO for this problem