# IOS - UIViewController won't rotate

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, gallery, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UITabbar` inside a `UINavigationController` base app. On one off the tabs I've some tumbnails of photos, and when I tap on one of the photos, I go to another `UIViewController` (push to the nav stack) and have the photos in Fullscreen.

I have two problems with that:

1- I can't rotate, or even make a `NSLog` of the rotation. I have the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` returning YES, and i've tried the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` methods, with a simple `NSLog`, but it doesn't worked at all.

2- When I hit the back button, and come back to the tab of thumbnails, I still have these thumbnails, but i don't have the tabbar any more.

Comment: How? Do I do that? And what influences it?

Comment: I will review my questions now! 

Tks for the help Jacky (between, is there any Portuguese IOS community?, I'm from Aveiro, and I'm in IOS by two months). And do you know the aweser to my question? :)

Comment: I would probably have to check your project to see what's wrong with it. You can join the portuguese iOS Development group on linkedin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just throw my two cents:

When you are using a `UITabBar` application, **all** `UIViewController's` should allow rotation in order for you to rotate one of them. Although there are some workarounds for this behavior, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100309/rotate-one-uiviewcontroller-in-uitabbar-application) answer and [this](http://arashpayan.com/blog/2008/09/04/change-iphoneipod-app-orientation-within-a-uitabbarcontroller/) article.